# Finding an Account match based on domain from email field in user form

Tags: salesforce, simple-salesforce, salesforce-flow

We are trying to improve the flow for our new user access request to our customer portal. We needed to implement some features immediately without the ability to provide customer training and the original build (by a contractor) didn't have any contextual help. This is causing approval routing issues and the need for manual editing of the user-inputted details.

**current flow:** new users requesting system access enter details including email, and either an existing account or a new account,

**issues:**
*Our accounts are mostly Counties and Municipalities*

- They rarely choose the correct team and leave the default choice
- They often attempt to create a new account because of account naming conventions.
- ex: the convention for municipality accounts is [NAME], [type] of, not [type] of [Name]
- ex: typing [Name] County Board of Commissioners instead of [Name] County

**goal flow:**

- new user enters email
- domain checked for match to account.
- user asked to verify account

**Choice A:**

- add a field to account_c with the domain
- strip domain from email and search (new resource formula?)
- matches found
- create a record choice set radio selection for account choice
- no match
- new screen, provide search bar and new account choices

**Choice B:**

- As A without the field addition, searching on users. I'm not sure how to do this

**Choice C: **

- Create a new object with a parent-child relationship to account_c with domains to allow for accounts that have multiple domains

I think that Choice C is the best choice.

Do I have a good handle on this?

**Thanks In Advance, **

I haven't tried anything yet. It has been a year since I've done any work in flow and I only have a dev sandbox right now. I don't want to mess with importing test data if I don't have to.